# Firing Colorbox Slideshows Based on Parent DIV

Tags: jquery, colorbox

This is probably a fairly novice jQuery / Colorbox question but I haven't been able to stumble upon a solution.

On one of my pages, I have multiple [Colorbox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/) slideshows which have as a parent a DIV with a unique ID value, see the code below for a slimmed down example.

How can I best code things so when #display_59 > a.slides_colorbox is clicked, only the images in that particular slideshow will be displayed?

That is, if the user clicks on the images within #display_59, only IMG_3440.jpg and IMG_3441.jpg will be displayed?

```
<div id="display_59" class="display">
   <div class="slides_thumbs">
     <a class="slides_colorbox" href="/images/IMG_3440.JPG"><img src="/images/made/public/burns/IMG_3440_thumb.JPG" alt="" width="62" height="62" /></a>
     <a class="slides_colorbox" href="/images/IMG_3441.JPG"><img src="/images/made/public/burns/IMG_3441_thumb.JPG" alt="" width="62" height="62" /></a>
   </div>
</div>

<div id="display_60" class="display">
   <div class="slides_thumbs">
     <a class="slides_colorbox" href="/images/IMG_2444.JPG"><img src="/images/made/public/burns/IMG_2444_thumb.JPG" alt="" width="62" height="62" /></a>
     <a class="slides_colorbox" href="/images/IMG_2445.JPG"><img src="/images/made/public/burns/IMG_2445_thumb.JPG" alt="" width="62" height="62" /></a>
   </div>
</div>

...
```

To run the slideshow, I'm using this line, which is pretty much as stock as it comes.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 (".slides_colorbox").colorbox({rel:'slides_colorbox', slideshow:false});
});
```

Which, as expected, adds all four images to the slideshow. (For context, each slideshow is connected to a blog entry. Since the number of entries will change, there will be an unknown quantity of #display_XX DIVs.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
$('.display').each(function(i){
  var groupName = 'group'+i;
  $('.slides_colorbox', this).colorbox({rel:groupName});
});
```

Comment: This was pretty darn close, Jack. I've added my own answer below to better show the tweaks I made to get this working. Many thanks!

Comment: Doh!  I made a mistake by not adding a context to the selector.  Edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

[Jack's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18422441/800615) answer was oh so very close! I was able to get it to work by making a couple tweaks: I replaced .slides_colorbox in my HTML with .groupX (for group1, group2, etc) and firing on that class.

```
$('.display').each(function(i){   
  var groupName = 'group'+(i+1);
  $("."+groupName).colorbox({rel:groupName});
});
```

The `'group'+(i+1);` is because the page is powered by ExpressionEngine and I need to add +1 so groupName is aligned with the zero-based {count} tag.